# rich:modalPanel appearing for some seconds only

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have used rich:menuItem to display rich:modalpanel. Code of rich:menuItem is as follow:

```
<rich:menuItem>
    <a4j:commandLink
        value="Add Machine"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('addMachinePanel')}.show()"
        reRender="addMachinePanel">
   </a4j:commandLink>
</rich:menuItem>
```

And rich:modalpanel  code is

```
<rich:modalPanel id="addMachinePanel">
    <a4j:form>
        <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel"
            action="#{adminBean.cleanupMachineToEdit}"
            onclick="#{rich:component('addMachinePanel')}.hide(); return false;" />
    </a4j:form>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

With above piece of code, rich:modalpanel is appearing for one or two seconds and again disappear.
Please help me to find out the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default , the `submitMode`  attribute for the `rich:menuItem` is `server` , which will submit the form  and completely refreshes the page.

You can change the `submitMode`  to the  `ajax` to performs an ajax form submission. Only the elements specified with the `reRender` attribute will be refreshed instead of whole page.

Or , you can change it to `none` (for richfaces 3.X) or `client` (for richface 4.0)  such that there are no form submission.

```
<rich:menuItem submitMode="ajax">
    <a4j:commandLink
        value="Add Machine"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('addMachinePanel')}.show()"
        reRender="addMachinePanel">
   </a4j:commandLink>
</rich:menuItem>
```